# Main thread never yields to goroutine

Tags: go

- edit * -- uncomment the two runtime lines and change Tick() to Sleep() and it works as expected, printing one number every second.  Leaving code as is so answer/comments make sense.

go version go1.4.2 darwin/amd64

When I run the following, I never see anything printed from `go Counter()`.

```
package main

import (
  "fmt"
  "time"
  //"runtime"
)

var count int64 = 0

func main() {
  //runtime.GOMAXPROCS(2)
  fmt.Println("main")
  go Counter()
  fmt.Println("after Counter()")
  for {
    count++
  }
}

func Counter() {
  fmt.Println("In Counter()")
  for {
    fmt.Println(count)
    time.Tick(time.Second)
  }
}

> go run a.go
main
after Counter()
```

If I uncomment the runtime stuff, I will get some strange results like the following all printed at once (not a second apart):

```
> go run a.go
main
after Counter()
In Counter()
10062
36380
37351
38036
38643
39285
39859
40395
40904
43114
```

What I expect is that `go Counter()` will print whatever count is at every second while it is incremented continuously by the main thread.  I'm not so much looking for different code to get the same thing done.  My question is more about what is going on and where am I wrong in my expectations?  The second results in particular don't make any sense, being printed all at once.  They should never be printed closer than a second apart as far as I can tell, right?

Comment: I think you have mistaken `time.Tick` for `time.Sleep`.

Comment: Turns out this change fixes it so it runs as expected (with GOMAXPROCS=2).

Comment: Yup, all mysteries solved in under 10 minutes. Viva SO!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is nothing in your tight `for` loop that lets the Go scheduler run.
The schedule considers other goroutines whenever one blocks or on some (which? all?) function calls.

Since you do neither the easiest solution is to add a call to [`runtime.Gosched`](https://golang.org/pkg/runtime/#Gosched). E.g.:

```
for {
    count++
    if count % someNum == 0 {
        runtime.Gosched()
    }
}
```

Also note that writing and reading the same variable from different goroutines without locking or synchronization is a data race and [**there are no benign data races**](https://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2013/01/06/benign-data-races-what-could-possibly-go-wrong), your program could do *anything* when reading a value as it's being written. (And synchronization would also let the Go scheduler run.)

For a simple counter you can avoid locks by using [`atomic.AddInt64(&var, 1)`](https://golang.org/pkg/sync/atomic/#AddInt64) and [`atomic.LoadInt64(&var)`](https://golang.org/pkg/sync/atomic/#LoadInt64).

Further note (as pointed out by @tomasz and completely missed by me), `time.Tick` doesn't delay anything, you may have wanted `time.Sleep` or `for range time.Tick(…)`.

Comment: Excellent answer (can't accept it for another 6 minutes).

Comment: Switching to time.Sleep() with GOMAXPROCS=2 and it works as expected.  I know this bit of code was a mess with a data race in it, but I was trying to distill the problem from something much bigger in order to ask the question you ended up answering.  Thank you.